# Can't load the desktop after LightDM screen

Tags: 11.10, gnome, lightdm, hp-pavilion

I've just installed Oneiric in my HP Pavillion dv6000. The installation was fine, it finished without a problem. I rebooted the laptop and it went to the LightDM screen I typed my password and as it was loading the desktop it stop and came back to the lightDM screen.

I think it was a hardware problem and I tried to install Classic Gnome desktop on Terminal. It was fine again (the terminal after <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> works fine)

When I choose Classic Gnome no effects the problem is he same. it came back to the lightGDM screen.

Can someone help me?

Comment: try to delete the ~/.ICEauthority file, for me I had to install gdm to actually know the problem was there.

Comment: Do you get any error in .xsession-errors when getting the issue?

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyways or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reasons why you want it open. Regards