# Screen glitch on boot, goes away if I close and open notebook

Tags: 16.04, boot, drivers, gpu, gpu-driver

I'm using a Aspire One ZG5 notebook. It's 32bits.
My Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS
My GPU is a onboard intel one, Intel 945GME x86/MMX/SSE2.

The problem is the following, when I turn the notebook on, after the bios the screen turns purple as usual. But then everything turns black, except a little purple stripe up the screen. Then a lot of, I don't know, random glitchy unreadable text appears on the left three quarters of the screen, then I wait some time and the right one quarter of the screen is all normal, showing my desktop.

Then if I move my mouse cursor to the buggy side of the screen, it still shows up. If I click the upper left corner of the screen, where the dash button is located, it lauches the dash, but again, I can only see it at the right side of the screen.

If I then close the notebook, open it and press the power button (to get back from sleep), everything is back to normal. I just have to type in the password and it's good to go.
My girlfriend is using it this way for some weeks now. She turns it on, wait for the desktop to appear at the right, close it, open again, hit the button, writes her password and use it normally.
It's kinda annoying to go through all this ritual every single time, so I hope theres a way to fix this. I think it's related to the gpu drivers, but I don't know how this happened, since it was fine some time ago and my girlfriend doesn't even know how to update drivers.

I took some photos (if I take a screenshot, the screen looks normal on the image, so I had to take photos with my phone) but I haven't used this site for ages so I don't remember how to post them...

Comment: Haha your girlfriend has lots of patience! I'd throw the damn thing out the window. I ***think*** what you need to do is reload `lightdm` later in the boot cycle. Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/68025/cant-load-the-desktop-after-lightdm-screen and https://askubuntu.com/questions/324807/lightdm-doesnt-load-on-boot and